# Format datetime-local in html5 to DD/MM/YYYY in date part and 24 hour in time part

Tags: django, html, datetimepicker, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am developping a django project and use the element `datetime-local` in HTML like `<input type="datetime-local" name="starttime" value={{startTimeString}}>` and `<input type="datetime-local" name="endtime" value="2015-07-10T19:00:00">`, since I need a datetime range.

Its format on browser is `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM(PM)`, but in my country, The convention is `DD/MM/YYYY` and 24 hour format. How can I change it?

What I want to change is just the format of the element showing on the web page. and if possible to set the format of `datetime-local`, I prefer to not split it to two separate selectors: date and time.

Thank you very much for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you should make minor data settings in your code.

```
 example:   <p>Today: {{ Today|date:"M d, Y" }}</p>
```

Make time settings accordingly to this, too.

this could help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format